# How to create and apply styles through programming in android?

Tags: android, coding-style

I am new to Android app. development. I need to change the existing style at runtime or can create new styles at runtime and I need to apply it for my buttons and textviews..

Can any one suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to do so (most of them are provided by the super class [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)):

- `setTextColor` to change the color of foreground
- `setTypeface` to change the font style
- `setBackgroundResource(int)` to change its backgrond
- `setPadding` to add padding

All of them work for `EditText`, `Button` and others, since most of them extends the `TextView` class. So, my suggestion is: RTFM... just kidding... read the documentation to see the available functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I was trying to do something similar.
This links gave me enough info:

- [Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)
- [Custom Android Button Style and Theme](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/)
- [Understanding Android Themes And Styles](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/)