# Android Programming: In main.xml, how do I change the layout for ALL my components?

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I'm new to Android programming, so I have no idea how this works.
If, for example, all my `Buttons` and `TextViews` are supposed to have the attribute `android:layout_marginTop="10dip"`, how can I do this in an easier way than defining it for every single component, e.g.:

```
<Button
android:id="..."
...
android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

<TextView
android:id="..."
...
android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

<TextView
android:id="..."
...
android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

...
```

And where can I find a documentation of all the different tags that can be used in `main.xml`? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Create `style` for your app : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074041/how-to-create-and-apply-styles-through-programming-in-android and this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: You can add the layout margin to the top most layout of your xml.By this all your views will have a margin of that amount.